# How to find out if a Skype call is currently active on Android

Tags: android, skype, android-package-managers

Okay, I decompiled Skype's manifest to find out if there are any Services or Broadcasts running during a call.
There are only a few internal broadcasts for incoming calls. Also only one receiver and one service exist.

I monitored all running services with my app, but the SkypeMainService is always running, even if not in a call.

Also `AudioMode` is not changed by skype (but according to the logcat-logs the dev wanted to, but they just don't do it), so I cannot simply check if it is `MODE_IN_CALL`.

Do you have any suggestions how to find out, if Skype is currently running and having an active call?

Thanks!

/edit: A brief overview of the Activities etc:

```
<activity android:name="com.skype.raider.Main">
<activity-alias android:name="com.skype.raider.ui.SplashScreenActivity" android:targetActivity="com.skype.raider.Main">
<receiver android:name="com.skype.MainReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
   <action android:name="com.skype.raider.INCOMING_GSM_CALL" />
   <action android:name="com.skype.raider.ON_GSM_CALL" />
   <action android:name="com.skype.raider.intent.action.request_sync" />
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.skype.MainService">
```

Comment: I don't use Skype, but if there's an *active* call then won't SkypeActivity (or whatever it's called) be the foreground activity? Which can obviously be detected through ActivityManager...

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought too - but Skype does actually have only two activities declared: A Splashscreen Activity and a Main Activity. The MainActivity does everything, even handling calls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I really hoped someone would provide a useful answer. However, I picked up Reuben's advice in the comment and made this method:

```
/**
 * Gets the current activity
 * 
 * @param context
 *            A context to use
 * @return The Activity name
 */
public static String getCurrentTopActivity(Context context) {
    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);
    return ar.topActivity.getClassName().toString();
}
```

Then I check if the result equals  `com.skype.raider.Main`. This will also return true if there is *no* active Skype call, but the main app is open.

Thanks for all the help, especially Reuben!

**Edit:** Your will need the following permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: Its not working for me, I used this code in my background service. Is there any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

The day Skype changes any of this (might be in that update that's coming in 2 days from now - before you finish coding) your code might break. So I don't think its worth attempting anything of this sort.

I am sorry, this might not be an "answer", but I don't think time invested into this is worth it.

Comment: I am completely aware of that. However, I asked for a solution for the current software, not a future-proof solution. And what do you mean with the update? Is there an update announced to be released within the next two days?

Answer (score -1):

There is a few things that you can do to increase your chance of guessing it:

1) Check if the application is running:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

2) Check the phone state for data exchanging using the [PhoneManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK)

3) and finally check Skype [developers page](http://developer.skype.com/) for any known api

Comment: No, like I said before, it doesn't make sense to check if the Skype Process is running (**it is always running**) and in addition **there are no Android APIs** on that site.

Comment: Also as I wrote in the question, the phone state is not changed.